# ansible mysql "check_implicit_admin" (without root user password)

Tags: mysql, ansible

I try to create a database with ansible and a user with database permissions.

The current mysql setup is the basic config after installation on ubuntu 20.04.
mysql server: 8.0.24

A root mysql password is not setup and I can access mysql without password

```
sudo mysql ...
```

Why ansible force to use a password?

check_implicit_admin sould work in this case?

Ansible configuration:

```
- name: Create a new database with name 'db_example'
  community.mysql.mysql_db:
  check_implicit_admin: yes
  login_user: root
  login_password: ''
  name: db_example
  state: present

- name: Create database user with name 'userx' and database privileges
  community.mysql.mysql_user:
  check_implicit_admin: yes
  login_user: root
  login_password: ''
  name: userx
  password: userx_password
  priv:
  'db_exampmle.*': 'ALL,GRANT'
  state: present
```

Ansible error:

```
TASK [Create a new database with name 'db_example'] **********************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or /root/.my.cnf has the credentials. Exception message: (1698, \"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'\")"}
```

I tried to set a password with:

`sudo mysql -u root --execute="SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = 'pass';"`

Same error message in ansible,
changed value:
`login_password: 'pass'`

Comment: **only** sudo mysql needs no password, you use it to configure or problem handle mysql, but for every thing else you need a password. Have you run mysql secure installation?

Comment: no, can I add this in ansible? i tried to change/set the root password with ansible, but the current password is required (same error).

Comment: you need to run the mysql shell command before you run ansible

Comment: the complete configuration should be over ansible

Comment: look at https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-mysql maybe this will help

Answer (score 1):

MySQL allows admin access when root but only when the client is using a socket connection.

If you add
login_unix_socket: "/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"
it'll work from the ansible client the same way as the mysql client.
That's the socket used in Ubuntu 20.04, other systems or versions might differ.